# Displaying the elements of 2d array

Tags: java

> simple 2d array of 4x6

```
public class arraytest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
int array[][] = new int[4][6];
int row = array.length;
int col = array[0].length;

System.out.println("Row length " + row);
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
    array[1][1] = 5;
    System.out.println("Array elements " + array[i][j]);
    }
}

}
```

> how does array[1][1]=5 functions:
>   The output is as follows:

```
Row length 4
Array elements 0
Array elements 0
Array elements 0
Array elements 0
Array elements 0
Array elements 0
Array elements 0
Array elements 5
Array elements 0
Array elements 0
Array elements 0
Array elements 0
Array elements 0
Array elements 0
Array elements 0
Array elements 0
Array elements 0
Array elements 0
Array elements 0
Array elements 0
Array elements 0
Array elements 0
Array elements 0
Array elements 0
```

> how come "Array elements 5" is in 8th position, i couldnt understand the logic. >can anyone explain the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with arrays you must know that the first element is always stored in the 0 index. I assume that by typing array[1][1] you wanted to store the value 5 in the first row, first column. However [1][1] actually refers to second row second column for the reason stated above.

Therefore your array looks like this:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 5 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Finally, because your for loops has columns as the innermost loop, it will print out each column in the first row before moving to the second row. So the first row outputs six 0s and the second row outputs another 0 before you finally hit the value you set as the eighth output.

Answer (score 0):

array[1][1] represents the intersection of second row and second column. Therefore loop firstly prints the first line (which has 6 elements) and in the second row, prints  array[1][0] and  array[1][1]. So,  array[1][1] is in 8th position.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the element 1,1  to 5... the rest will hold the same value...

```
Row length 4 
Array elements 0 
Array elements 0 
Array elements 0 
Array elements 0 
Array elements 0 
Array elements 0 
Array elements 0
Array elements 5  <--- here is he!!
Array elements 0 
Array elements ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to Java, arrays will begin with an index of 0; just like the first char of a String is 0. Consider lengths, or the final index of an array or String as, n-1. This 0 indexed logic will also apply to the columns/rows of a 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

**See the Output of this example, your doubt will clear:**

```
public class arraytest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
int array[][] = new int[4][6];
int row = array.length;
int col = array[0].length;

System.out.println("Row length " + row);
System.out.println("Col length " + col);
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
    array[1][1] = 5;
    System.out.println("Array elements at row "+i+" and column "+j+" is "+ array[i][j]);
    }
}

}
```

**Output:**

```
Row length 4                                                                                                                                                                    
Col length 6                                                                                                                                                                    
Array elements at row 0 and column 0 is 0                                                                                                                                       
Array elements at row 0 and column 1 is 0                                                                                                                                       
Array elements at row 0 and column 2 is 0                                                                                                                                       
Array elements at row 0 and column 3 is 0                                                                                                                                       
Array elements at row 0 and column 4 is 0                                                                                                                                       
Array elements at row 0 and column 5 is 0                                                                                                                                       
Array elements at row 1 and column 0 is 0                                                                                                                                       
Array elements at row 1 and column 1 is 5                                                                                                                                       
Array elements at row 1 and column 2 is 0                                                                                                                                       
Array elements at row 1 and column 3 is 0                                                                                                                                       
Array elements at row 1 and column 4 is 0                                                                                                                                       
Array elements at row 1 and column 5 is 0                                                                                                                                       
Array elements at row 2 and column 0 is 0                                                                                                                                       
Array elements at row 2 and column 1 is 0                                                                                                                                       
Array elements at row 2 and column 2 is 0                                                                                                                                       
Array elements at row 2 and column 3 is 0                                                                                                                                       
Array elements at row 2 and column 4 is 0                                                                                                                                       
Array elements at row 2 and column 5 is 0                                                                                                                                       
Array elements at row 3 and column 0 is 0                                                                                                                                       
Array elements at row 3 and column 1 is 0                                                                                                                                       
Array elements at row 3 and column 2 is 0                                                                                                                                       
Array elements at row 3 and column 3 is 0                                                                                                                                       
Array elements at row 3 and column 4 is 0                                                                                                                                       
Array elements at row 3 and column 5 is 0
```